# Bootstrap intervals from a sample not obtained with 'boot'

Tags: r, confidence-interval, bootstrap

I have a bootstrap sample of a parameter and I want to calculate the confidence intervals that 'boot.ci' from the R package 'boot' produces: "norm","basic","perc","bca"and "stud; but I do not have an object of class 'boot',  I just have the bootstrap sample.

Do you know another package that I could use for this purpose?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Of course, percentile intervals are easy to obtain. I just wanted to check a general alternative for the others.

Comment: @Elvis, thanks. +1 for the open access reference!

Comment: You can find example computations in R for "norm", "basic", "perc", and "stud" (but not for bca) in [this answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9104/coverage-probabilities-of-the-basic-bootstrap-confidence-interval/9161#9161).

Answer (score 6):

Have a look on [Bootstrap Methods for Standard Errors, Confidence Intervals, and Other Measures of Statistical Accuracy](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/statistical-science/volume-1/issue-1/Bootstrap-Methods-for-Standard-Errors-Confidence-Intervals-and-Other-Measures/10.1214/ss/1177013815.full) (Efron and Tibshirani). All classical methods for bootstrap confidence intervals are described in details and are easy to implement.