# How to select the bandwith of smoothed bootstrap for building confidence intervals?

Tags: confidence-interval, bootstrap, smoothing

I am interested in non-parametric methods for building confidence intervals for an estimator (e.g. the mean) using few samples (e.g. 10). I think I have read somewhere that smoothing the bootstrapped estimator values can improve the quality of the derived percentiles interval. However I could not find any online reference that explains how to tune the bandwidth of the smoothing step.

Comment: I am not an expert, but I do not think that smoothed bootstrap  *always* performs better. Anyway, in some cases it might be and a standard smooth estimate of a continuous pdf is the kernel
density estimation for which there is a huge amount of literature on how to choose the bandwidth h including rules which make reference to the normal distribution, or cross-validation methods.

Comment: For example, you can find details here: http://www.google.be/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=choice%20bandwidth%20kernel%20density&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDwQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.44.6770%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&ei=psGgT_WDLoag8gO3qcC9CA&usg=AFQjCNGGQORw2z4nqfm6rl9V33M912EU6A&cad=rja

Comment: In line with @ocram's comment, you might be interested on comparing different types of bootstrap intervals. Take a look at this [question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24082/bootstrap-intervals-from-a-sample-not-obtained-with-boot).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to be answering so late.  This question came just when I joined CV and i only found it by looking back.  For your specific question about using the bootstrap in kernel density estimation  I think you will find material in [Bernard Silverman's book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0412246201).  I think he covers the use of bootstrap for bandwidth selection.

[Efron and Tibshirani](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0412042312) discuss the bootstrap for finding modes of a density via kernel methods.

Oddly there is not really much on it in the general text on bootstrap including mine. Maybe in the next edition I will add something.

Comment: I think the OP is asking a slightly different question which is about using kernel density estimation for producing improved confidence intervals when the bootstrap sample is small: **"I am interested in non-parametric methods for building confidence intervals for an estimator (e.g. the mean) using few samples (e.g. 10)"**.

Comment: That was my impression as well @Procrastinator (+1). Michael, note that there's no need to apologize for answering late. In fact, I believe that attending to old questions is actually encouraged, as evidenced by the existence of the Necromancer, Revival and Archaeologist badges.

Comment: Thanks guys. I know I was not directly answering the question but it was my impression that the OP might have been a little misinformed or misinterpreted what he read.  With respect to bootstrap confidence intervals there are many variations that adjust the endpoints.  Those I am familiar with but not anything applying a smoothed bootstrap.  Of course there is a smoothed bootstrap which involves sampling from a kernel density fit to the original sample.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap confidence intervals

Thomas J. DiCiccio and Bradley Efron
Source: Statist. Sci. Volume 11, Number 3 (1996), 189-228.

[Link](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/statistical-science/volume-11/issue-3/Bootstrap-confidence-intervals/10.1214/ss/1032280214.full)

Keywords: Bootstrap-t; BCa and ABC methods; calibration; second-order accuracy